# Can we enable orderSetting using apex code?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

If yes please guide me how to enable Order Setting using apex code.

```
 HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request = new HttpRequest();

    request.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/31.0');

    request.setMethod('POST');  

    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    request.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'update');               

     String b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

            b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';

            b += '<soapenv:Header>';

            b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';

            b += '<ns1:sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</ns1:sessionId>';

            b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';

            b += '</soapenv:Header>';

            b += '<soapenv:Body>';



            b += '<update xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';

            b += '<UpdateMetadata>';

            b += '<currentName>OrderSettings</currentName>';



            b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:OrderSettings" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';



            b += '<fullName>OrderSettings</fullName>';

            b += '<enableQuote>true</enableQuote>';



            b += '</metadata>';

            b += '</UpdateMetadata>';

            b += '</update>';

            b += '</soapenv:Body>';

            b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        request.setBody(b);

        request.setCompressed(false);



    //request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);



    String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();

    system.debug('Hello from body'+body);
```

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/how-to-activate-an-order-programmatically-without-setting-the-status-field-to-a

Comment: i am getting error code 500.

Comment: This happens when you requested a resource that doesn’t exist. Make sure ID,NAMES everything is in place and correct - double check everything.

Comment: I am trying to enable order Setting using metadata api where i put <fullName>OrderSettings</fullName>;
<enableOrders>true</enableOrders>;